# Var args of different type return segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I have code in which I have used in varargs one is of type long and the other is of type char array, and it is passed to a function with variable number of argument (...) and when I try to retrieve the char [] it is throwing a segmentation fault.

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int varargs(int num,...);

int main()
{
   printf("enter fflush\n");
   long opr=77777;
   long *ptr=&opr;
   char env[10]="QATNLO19\0";
   varargs(2,* ptr,env);
   return 0;
}

int varargs(int num,...)
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap,num);
    printf("getting char arg\n"); 
    fflush (stdout);
    char *ptr=va_arg(ap,char *); // segmentation fault at this line 
    printf("char is %s",ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Can you explain why this is a segmentation fault?

Comment: Please don't add `**` to the code to highlight a line, it can be confused with C syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first variadic argument passed to the function is `*ptr` which has type `long`.  You're attempting to read it as if it were a `char *`.  That triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to read the `long` argument first before you can read the `char *`.  You also need to call `va_end` when you're finished reading the arguments.

```
long l = va_arg(ap,long);
char *ptr = va_arg(ap,char *);
va_end(ap);
```